# some portion of botton of program,terminal and application are not appearing?

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, oracle

[image]

[image]

I had installed Xubuntu on virtual box but on shifiting on full screen mode some portion of botton of program,terminal and application are not appearing making diffcult to work?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Can you add screenshots in your question as well?

Comment: Adding the release of Xubuntu maybe also helpful (*the GUI may not have changed much, but the code underneath has completed the port from GTK2 to GTK3, so knowing where your software is can also be useful*).